# How can I fix this - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'label.toUpperCase')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I fix this error in React Navigation V3?....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

> Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
import DrawerClose from './DrawerCloseButton'
import DrawerOpen from './DrawerOpenButton'
import HeaderButtons from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';


import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

const WIDTF = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
  drawerWidth: WIDTF*0.80,
  drawertType: 'back'    
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator ({
Home: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
},
},
DrawerConfig
);

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Drawermenu:{
    screen: Drawer,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { state } = navigation;
      if (state.routes[ state.index ].key !== 'DrawerClose') {
        return {

          headerLeft: (
            <HeaderButtons IconComponent={ Icon } iconSize={ 24 } color={ 'black' }>
            <HeaderButtons.Item iconName="close" onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle') } />
          </HeaderButtons>
          )
        };
      } 
      else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }
});

export default createAppContainer (MainNavigator);
```

Here is the Error:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any `label` from the code you have.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: there's no `label.toUpperCase()` in  your code. you added the code that doesn't cause the error.

Comment: Yes me too, and I can't figure out why am I receiving this error

Comment: it should tell you where the error is, the line and which file this's happening in. Please check your logs

Comment: No it doesn't. It's just the error

Comment: in your editor search for `label.toUpperCase()`. If you don't know your own code, how are we going to help you.

Comment: Can you see the image I add in the question ?

Comment: it say the error is in `HeaderButtons .js` line 80

Comment: Yes, but I don't have HeaderButtons.js component. It's a library. Oh I found it, sorry

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file call it `MyHeaderButtons.js` and use `MaterialHeaderButtons` instead of `HeaderButtons`

```
// MyHeaderButtons.js

import * as React from 'react';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { HeaderButtons, HeaderButton } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

export const Item = HeaderButtons.Item;

// define IconComponent, color, sizes and OverflowIcon in one place
const MaterialHeaderButton = props => (
  <HeaderButton {...props} IconComponent={MaterialIcons} iconSize={23} color="blue" />
);

export const MaterialHeaderButtons = props => {
  return (
    <HeaderButtons
      HeaderButtonComponent={MaterialHeaderButton}
      OverflowIcon={<MaterialIcons name="more-vert" size={23} color="white" />}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

replace `import HeaderButtons from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';` from your imports with `import { MaterialHeaderButtons, Item } from './MyHeaderButtons'`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation'; 
import DrawerClose from './DrawerCloseButton'
import DrawerOpen from './DrawerOpenButton'
import { MaterialHeaderButtons, Item } from './MyHeaderButtons'; // new import
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Remove

```
<HeaderButtons IconComponent={ Icon } iconSize={ 24 } color={ 'black' }>
  <HeaderButtons.Item iconName="close" onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle') } />
</HeaderButtons>
```

use

```
<MaterialHeaderButtons IconComponent={Icon} iconSize={24} color={'black'}>
  <Item
       iconName="close"
       onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}/>
</MaterialHeaderButtons>
```

To use the hamburger menu with the following component

```
class MenuButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());   
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Hamburger
          active={this.state.active}
          type="cross"
          onPress={this.onPress}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

headerLeft: <MenuButton navigation={navigation} />,
```

[working demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/graceful-ramen)

Comment: It runs but the button is just an X and it doesn't open the drawer. Can you make it somehow to be a menu button and when it open the drawer to goes like X

Comment: I'll be so thankful if you can do it, because till now I found examples only for react-navigation V1 and V2

Comment: I update your imports `import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';`

Comment: do you see my changes?

Comment: Yes it runs, I want to ask

Comment: Is it going to run if I change the Item with <Hamburger /> (Button). Animated button

Comment: *Is it going to run if I change the Item with <Hamburger /> (Button). Animated button* I'm not sure just play around with it, if doesn't work you can always come  here and ask for help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help

Comment: No, it didn't work :(. But can that be done with this library I'm using now?

Comment: you can use `<Icon />` for hamburger menu.

Comment: You mean "from" Hamburger menu ? Or I didn't get it ?

Comment: see my updated answer. list of icons https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/

Comment: The problem is that the animation action for Hamburger is not just an Icon see my answer bellow

Comment: is `Hamburger` from https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-hamburger?

Comment: It's working  using the component you posted, see https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/graceful-ramen