# What is the problem with HeaderButtons.js?

Tags: react-native

Whenever I use "HeaderButtons" in my code in react-native, I receive this error:

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'label.toUpperCase').
this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {CATEGORIES} from '../Data/dummy-data';
import Colors from '../Constants/Colors';
import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens';
import CategoryGridTile from '../components/CategoryGridTile';
import {HeaderButtons} from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/Ionicons';

enableScreens();

const CategoriesScreen = props => {
    const renderGridItem = (itemData) => {
        return (
            <CategoryGridTile 
            title={itemData.item.title} 
            onSelect={() => props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: 'CategoryMeal',
                params: {
                    categoryId: itemData.item.id
                },
            })}
            color = {itemData.item.color}    
            />
        );
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
          <FlatList 
          data={CATEGORIES} 
          numColumns={2} 
          renderItem={renderGridItem}
          keyExtractor = {(itemData) => itemData.id} 
          />
        </View>
    );
};
CategoriesScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Meal Categories',
    headerLeft:(<HeaderButtons>
        <Ionicons name='ios-menu' onPress={()=> {}}/>
    </HeaderButtons>),

    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.HeaderColor,
    },
  headerTintColor: 'white',


};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,

    },

});
export default CategoriesScreen;
```

When I delete The HeaderButtons and I use merely Ionicons, there is no problem. 
what is wrong and how should I fix it? thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942559/how-can-i-fix-this-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-label-touppercase read this.

Comment: why dont you change the library as i can see there is a problem with the library.